# What is the best way to do parallel programming in python with APScheduler?

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, apscheduler

I'm using APScheduler to schedule tasks in python, and these tasks need to run independently and concurrently with another tasks.

The main rule is that these tasks have to be executed at the exact moment they were scheduled and cannot be blocked or delay execution because of another task.

The tasks are dynamically scheduled by the users of my application.

For that, when the task execution time arrives, I start a new sub-process to execute it:

```py
def _initialize_order_process(user, order):
    p = Process(target=do_scheduled_order, args=(user, order))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

It's important to know that each subprocess start a connection with a server.

And i'm scheduling my taks like this:

```py
scheduler.add_job(_initialize_order_process, 'date', run_date=start_time, args=[user, order], id=job_id)
```

My problem is when a large number of tasks are scheduled for the same time, due to the number of processes, the server crashes.

So, I  need this application to be scalable to support many users.

Does anyone know how to create a scalable solution for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add more hardware, horizontally (get more servers).

You add requests to a task queue, for example, using Redis, then delegate tasks using Celery workers, and run many parallel applications to pick up the workload

Another solution would be setup a cluster for Apache Airflow, then run tasks through it

> cannot be blocked or delay execution because of another task

Unfortunately, that's not how task scheduling works. Eventually, you will have jobs that depend on each other, and so you'll have to have a DAG of job processes